# How to use Shapely to plot squares/rectangles along a centre line

Tags: python, gis, shapely

How can Shapely be used to plot squares/rectangles along a centre line?

[image: A sketch of what I am trying to achieve]

In the sketch above, I would like to plot the red squares along the black line. The black line is a collection of (x, y) points.

Comment: The problem you propose is not completely specified. ¿do the squares have a fixed equal length? ¿where the centers are supposed to be placed (every fixed step or variable)? ¿should the squares cover the line? ¿can the squares overlap? ¿should the squares be touching each other?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the gaps with my question. The squares have a fixed equal length. The centres are supposed to be placed every fixed step. The squares have to cover the line. The squares cannot overlap but they have to be touching each other. Hope this clarifies my question.

Comment: Depending on the shape of the line and the length of the square, satisfy all those requirements is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString, Point, box
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# let's use a sine curve as our example line
x = np.arange(0, 3 * np.pi, 0.5)
y = np.sin(x)
xy = list(zip(x, y))
line = LineString(xy)
plt.plot(*line.xy)

# let's sample every 3 points along the line
x_samp = x[::3]
y_samp = y[::3]
plt.scatter(x_samp, y_samp)

# generate boxes along sampled points on the line
radius = (x_samp[1] - x_samp[0]) / 2
for i in range(len(x_samp)):
    box_loc = box(*Point(x_samp[i], y_samp[i]).buffer(radius).bounds)
    plt.plot(*box_loc.exterior.xy)

plt.axes().set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image]